# i can't use cvMorphologyEx in xcode4 with opencv2.3

Tags: xcode, opencv

when i use it, the Xcode show the "No matching function for call to  cvMorphologyEx"

but the Xcode can find its defines.

what happen?thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the documentation before asking such questions. If you had, you would have known that [`cv::morphologyEx`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyEx#morphologyex) is the function you're looking for.

Comment: now i know the reason. the function work in vs2008 but don't work in Xcode because of the params

Comment: Okay :) Can you may except the answer if it was useful?